# Displaying objects based on selected item from DropDownList in C#

Tags: selectedindexchanged

I have 4 different selections in the drop down list. If actions, say, is selected, then the hidden text boxes that relate to actions would be shown. The same goes for the other 3 selections. This is my first time ever using SelectedIndexChanged for a DropDownList, and I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Here is the C# code:

```
protected void DdlSelectType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string select = DdlSelectType.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        if (DdlSelectType.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "Action")
        {                
            DteActDate.Visible = true;
            TbActNotes.Visible = true;
            LblActNotes.Visible = true;
            BtnSaveAction.Visible = true;
            BtnCancelAction.Visible = true;
        }
```

I just need the objects in the if statement to show.

Comment: Totally redid the entire code for these methods. Used int values instead of string values and also used href and urls to determine when the DdlSelectType.SelectedIndex will choose action, task, etc.